# Assigning New Values to Variables in Java

Tags: java, variables

I am new to Java, and have a question about variables.  Here is an example.

```
int hello = 6;
int goodbye = 7;
int combined = hello + goodbye;

    System.out.println(combined);
    hello = 10;
    System.out.println(combined);
```

When I reassign hello, and give it the value of 10 instead of six, and I print combined the second time, it still says combined is equal to 13, not 17 in the console. How do you fix that?  Thank You!

Comment: That's how variables work.  You can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to recalculate `combined` because re-assigning a value to `hello` doesn't mean `combined` will get updated too. The value for `combined` is the one calculated using the current value (at that moment) of `hello`.

```
int hello = 6;
int goodbye = 7;
int combined = hello + goodbye;

System.out.println(combined);
hello = 10;
combined = hello + goodbye; // recalculate
System.out.println(combined);
```

Answer (score 2):

`combined` won't changed just because one of the variables determining it changed. You'll need to manually update `combined` every time.

For this simple case, the simplest way would just be to write `hello + goodbye` again as shown in @lealceldeiro's answer.

For more complicated bits of code though, instead of duplicating the same code multiple places, it would be better to wrap that code in a function:

```
public int doSomeMath(int x, int y) {
    return x + y; //Pretend this is some complicated equation 
}
```

Then, when you need to do the math later multiple times, you use the function:

```
int hello = 6;
int goodbye = 7;

// Prints 13
System.out.println(doSomeMath(hello, goodbye));

goodbye = 10;

//Prints 17 
System.out.println(doSomeMath(hello, goodbye));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `int` types, which will do everything *by value*. This means that it assigns `combined` a *copy* of the values of `hello` and `goodbye` added together.

They are totally separate and unconnected.

**Extra Reading**

- https://dzone.com/articles/java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value is an excellent article on this topic and should fill in the blanks for you.

Comment: `int` types (or even primitives) aren't treated in any special way as far as this question is concerned.

Comment: I don't know what passing by value/reference have to do with the question. Even if you pass by reference it won't update `combined` ever.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing variable combined not variable hello. To see change in combined you need to recalculate using expression.

```
int hello = 6; // hello has 6
int goodbye = 7; // goodbye has 7
int combined = hello + goodbye; // combined = 6 (value of hello) + 7 (value of goodbye) = 13

System.out.println(combined); //hence this prints value 13 which is assigned to combined
hello = 10; // changing the value of hello to 10.
System.out.println(combined); // since there is no change in combined value you will get 13 itself.

//In order to change the value of combined you need to assign the value again. In this case you need to re-evaluate combined.
combined = hello + goodbye; //Since now value of hello is 10.Expression will be 10 + 7 = 17
System.out.println(combined);//Output will be 17.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `combined` (or variables in a general sense) as a placeholder for integer values. So when executing `int combined = hello + goodbye;` you're filling the integer placeholder named `combined` with the sum of the values stored in the placeholders `hello` and `goodbye`. When you later execute `hello = 10;`, you're only putting a 10 in the placeholder named `hello`. This doesn't affect `combined` placeholder at all.

So resuming: when writing `int combined = hello + goodbye;` you're not saying that combined is the operation `hello + goodbye` but the result of that operation at the time when it was executed.